# Testing Chef script output in production

Tags: chef-infra

I have a Chef script that creates and configures couple of Linux servers on Amazon AWS. During the configuration step, it installs some software and installs the code from our project.

Is there a tool that can read the output of the Chef script (probably the log files) and provide me with information about the execution of the script? And point out if any step did not go smoothly?

There seems to be lots of content on TDD using Chef and unit testing but did not find any related to actual automated (or semi-automated) verification when the scripts are executed in production.

Comment: have you tried using Inspec or testkitchen? These are meant for that

Comment: Thank you. I had not heard of these tools. I will definitely try these.

Comment: But that's about TDD, which you excluded in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If chef cannot reach the desired state (as declared in the recipe). E.g. if you want to install a package which doesn't exist, it will fail and exit with non-zero exit code.